# DialogFlow EX integration is not displayed

Tags: dialogflow-es

In DialogFlow ES, the display of integration is gone.
Isn't the integration feature available in DialogFLow ES?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL05w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialogflow has limited features when working in a non default region. In your screenshot it shows that you have created your agent in the AS-NE region.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/region#limits

If you want to use integration you should create an agent in the default US region

Comment: solved. thank you very much.
It was helpful.

解決しました。本当にありがとうございます。
助かりました。

Comment: Good to hear! Please accept the answer and consider upvoting the answer :)